# How to send cookies from angular mock backend?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, httpbackend

I am currently involved in backendless development of app front-end using angular's **$httpBackend** service in ngMock module.

I am able to send responses for request using mock backend, but I haven't been able to find a method to send cookies using this service. I need these **cookies for user authentication and authorisation** purpose.Is there any way to send cookies from mock backend or any work around ?

Comment: do you see my answer? any feedbak?

Comment: Actually in my case, it is required the the cookie serves upfront in response to request for index.html page. I am using grunt server to serve the request for my app. I want the response (for index.html request) to be fetched from backend (passthrough the request), but only interfere with the header of the response to add cookies to it.Is this possible with angular?